# How can i test Smartfox server with Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Iam trying to send the SmartFox server requests through Beanshell postprocessor, but it is not working asynchronous. anyone working on Jmeter with Smartfox server please guide me.

My Scenario is:

1. Send HTTP Request to one server
2. Process the HTTP Response in Beanshell post processor
3. Using Smartfox server API, send the request to Smartfox server,
4. Wait for response from Smartfox server
5. Procees the received response
6. Exit.

Problem is Smartfox server API calls are Asynchronous, it is not waiting for response and sometimes wrong results received.